# Send an http request through UDP

Tags: php, udp

I need to send a simple http request to trigger an event through UDP protocol, I don't need to receive the response

Is it possible and how can I do it with php

Comment: Hope my answer below will help you with a problem.

Answer (score 0):

I think it should help you:

```
$server_ip = '127.0.0.1';
$server_port = 43278;
$message = 'Message';
$socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, SOL_UDP);
socket_sendto($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0, $server_ip, $server_port);
socket_close($socket);
```

More informations you can get at [PHP MANUAL: socket_sendto](http://php.net/manual/en/function.socket-sendto.php)

Comment: Why should the OP "try this"? A ***good answer*** will always have an explanation of what was done and why it was done in such a manner, not only for the OP but for future visitors to SO.